# Building a dict using zip

Tags: python

I have a list of names:

```
['john smith', 'sally jones', 'bob jones']
```

I want to build a dict in the following format:

```
{'john smith': [], 'sally jones': [], 'bob jones': []}
```

This is what happens when I try using zip

```
zip((all_crew_names, [[] for item in all_crew_names]))
[(['john smith', 'sally jones', 'bob jones'],), ([[], [], []],)]
```

What am I doing incorrectly here, and how would I properly zip this up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest solution here is a dictionary comprehension:

```
names = ['john smith', 'sally jones', 'bob jones']
d = {name: [] for name in names}
```

Note that it might be tempting to use `dict.fromkeys(names, [])`, but this would result in the *same* list being used for all keys.

Comment: For older Pythons that don't have dictionary comprehensions: `dict((name, []) for name in names)`

Answer (score 7):

You don't need `zip`.

```
{name: [] for name in all_crew_names}
```

In older versions of Python there was no such dictionary comprehension, so the following code can be used:

```
dict((name, []) for name in all_crew_names)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to actually use the `dict` constructor, and you have too many brackets:

```
dict(zip(all_crew_names, [[] for item in all_crew_names])
```

Comment: +1 for actually answering the "what am I doing incorrectly" part of the question